# NSFileManager: Trying to delete files, but it says they don't exist

Tags: ios, swift, nsfilemanager, foundation

I'm trying to delete the files in my cache directory. However, when I tried to delete individual folders, I got an error saying the file doesn't exist, even though I know it does. So, I tried using a for loop to delete the all the files in the caches directory.

```
do {
        for file in try NSFileManager.defaultManager().contentsOfDirectoryAtPath(cacheFolderPath) where !file.hasPrefix("."){
            try NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(file)
        }
        print("Cache cleared successfully.")
    }
    catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
        if let reason = error.localizedFailureReason {
            print(reason)
        }
    }
}
```

However, this code prints this:

> "CategoryThumbnails" couldn't be removed.
>   The file doesn't exist.

Well, it obviously does exist, as it was discovered by the `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` method! How can it not exist? Does anybody know what's going on here, and how I can clear the cache?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The results of `contentsOfDirectoryAtPath` is a list of files in the given folder. But each of those results is not a complete path itself.

To delete each `file`, you need to append `file` to `cacheFolderPath`. Then pass that complete path to `removeItemAtPath`.

Another solution is to use one of the other folder enumeration methods of `NSFileManager` that return full URLs and let your provide options to skip hidden files.